# What happened to Node.js builds for Raspberry Pi

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, compilation, raspberry-pi

Using [these](http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi) instructions I was able to easily install node.js on RPi. The problem was that since build v0.10.29 node.js has not included a build for the RPi. The current build is v0.10.31.

Does anyone know why node.js stopped including the RPi build with their new versions?

Is there a way to get the latest RPi build from another source?

This is my first question on SO, so hopefully I haven't mucked it up too much.

Comment: It's not a 100 % on topic question, but it might pass. Anyway, about raspi, I remember seeing this question and a discussion on node.js Google group, fix you try looking there?

Comment: I'm a noob. Please explain why the question is not 100% on topic. Thanks for the tip on the google group. I have done lots of web searching before posting the question and didn't find that.

Comment: Well, I think they're looking for mostly specific programming questions here, but now that I've revisited the FAQ, I see that common software tools are also ok. So, it is probably fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/nodejs/raspberry%7Csort:date/nodejs/XeBYb3cLN_Y/9hOJCFWgVV8J) Zlatko suggested. I found that Nathan Rajlich compiles the RPi builds, but has run into an issue since v0.10.29.

> Currently, however, v0.10.29 and v0.10.30 are failing to compile on ARM out-of-the-box. Follow this issue for updates on that: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8062.

It seems there is some hacking around to deal with the errors cropping up. It is beyond me, which is why I liked the node.js build for the RPi in the first place. I will continue with the old node.js build and hope for a RPi build in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these instructions here:https://github.com/audstanley/Node-MongoDb-Pi
You'll get nodejs v5.3.0 and MongoDb on the pi view the read me on how to install. Only four lines of code you'll need to copy paste into your CLi, and you'll have nodejs and MongoDb up in about five hours. (Mongodb takes quite some time to compile).